# Intercept redirection url request header in Angular application

Tags: angular, typescript, intercept

We have an application which is a combination of 2 sites, 1 site for login and another for the rest of the functionalities.Now on successful login, redirection will happen to the second site where all functionalities sit. The redirection request will contain headers which i want to intercept within my application, possible to do it using angular?
The request coming from other application is a post request.

Comment: If the server is returning a `301 redirect` response, the browser will catch this and strip all headers from the response before it reaches your angular handler. What type of response code are you getting ?

Comment: its 302 status code i am getting